# Non elementals: Lascaux vs. Sand Hawk vs Slagga DMG per second close range, which deals most damage?

Tags: borderlands-2

Ranked from 1 to 3, which would deal the most damage at close (point blank) range, assuming you empty their clips?

Let's assume slagga isn't slagged/ will never slag the enemy in this question. As well as the other weapons will never be elemental.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I have to mention that i only talk about the non-elemental SMGs here. Things like hellfire or good/bad touch were ignored.*

First of all, let's talk about the weapons themselves:

[**The Slagga**](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Slagga) is really bad in my opinion. The DMG on OP8 is around 125.000 per bullet, always slag element, firerate of 8.8 which is pretty good, but a reload time of 3.4 which is a lot for a SMG. Also, the Accuracy is not that great with only 70. So it fires fast, but not the best decision you can make since other SMGs are a lot stronger.

[**The Sandhawk**](http://de.borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Sand_Hawk) is a pretty good SMG. OP8 Dmg ranges around 175.000 and fires 8 bullets at the cost of 1 ammo. It reloads pretty fast (2.4) and it can be obtained with all elements. Downside: Slow firerate and the projectiles are extremely slow. So you will be unable to hit enemies far away if they move. Sandhawk is usually used for farming huge, stationary or slow enemies like terramorphous, the warrior or hyperius, especially in combination with the bee.

[**The Lascaux**](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Lascaux) is a crazy strong SMG. The OP8 DMG is around 200.000 and the burst fire count is just HUGE, so you deal crazy amounts of DMG if you aim down the sights. With a reload time of ~2.5 it reloads pretty fast, faster than most other SMGs. The general firerate is not that great, but usually, you shout aim anyways, so that doesn't matter that much. Also, the lascaux grants 100% recoil reduction, which is awesome! Downside: The spray pattern. It can be difficult to hit enemies far away. The lascaux is used for close- to midrange combat.

---

So, now to your question: If you assume every bullet hits, my vote goes to the sand hawk. Since this will only be the case if you fight raid bosses or other huge enemies, my rating goes like this:

**Against Raid Bosses:**

1. Sand Hawk
2. Lascaux
3. Slagga

**Against Casual Enemies:**

1. Lascaux
2. Sand Hawk
3. Slagga

**Edit/ Other options for good SMGs:**

[**Bitch**](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Bitch_%28Borderlands_2%29): So, the Bitch is a crazy strong SMG. I don't own a OP8 Bitch myself, but i think the DMG kicks in at 230.000 at OP8. Huge crits and really good accuracy which is achieve very fast compared to other hyperion SMGs. It's pretty much one of the best SMGs for long ranged combat. Especially zero profits from this one if you skilled the crit tree.

[**Actualizer**](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Actualizer): So, this thing is insane too. Huge amounts of DMG (OP8 kicks in at 320.000) and the rate of fire is at 8.7. Downside is the slow projectile speed and the increased reload time, but - in my opinion - if you don't play zero on the crit tree, this is the best non-elemental SMG in the game, even if it takes some time to get used to it.

[**Avenger**](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Avenger_%28Borderlands_2%29): So, this one is pretty much one of the best SMGs in the Game. The Stats are insane, below 2 second reloadtime, firerate above 9.0, DMG at OP8 kicks in at 250.000 if i remember right, i don't own one myself so i don't know the exact values. Also, it regenerates ammo when used which is awesome in extended fights like digistruct runs. Downside: It's REALLY rare and hard to obtain. But if you got one, you wield on of the best SMGs in the Game.

Comment: Are there better alternatives than the 3 I mentioned in the question that come to mind?? Pearlescents? Legendaries?

Comment: I mean, in the SMG department.

Comment: I added my 3 favourite **non-elemental** SMGs. But be aware that, if you use the bee shield, the sand hawk is still the best alternative.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad i could help.